# How to scale down the screen view using react-navigation with DrawerNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to scale down the screen view when the Drawer Content is open using react-navigation with DrawerNavigator. [You can see the expected behavior here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEKRp.gif) I'm not sure if is it possible, so suggestions using react-navigation are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-native-scaling-drawer](https://github.com/melihberberolu/react-native-scaling-drawer) supposed to work with `React Navigation v1`.

Let me know if you manage it to work with `v2`.

Comment: Were you able to run it with v3 or v2?